# Spring boot metrics with Jersey2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey, metrics

I have an application running spring-boot, jersey2 and spring metrics:
below is maven snippet:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Jersey used to work well until introducing actuator dependency.
Then following bean has been created to make Jersey working as filter:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean jerseyFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    bean.setName("jerseyFilter");
    bean.setFilter(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig()));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
    bean.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex", managementContextRegex);

    return bean;
}
```

Metrics are mapped to /admin path. With this configuration I cannot make metrics working. However by adding management.port (different than main app port) both Jersey resource and metrics are available.
What I'm missing here to make both metrics and Jersey resource start working on the same port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex"
```

This is the wrong property. That's for Jersey 1.x. For 2.x, it should be

```
"jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex"
```

<sub>See [`ServletProperties.FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletProperties.html#FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX)</sub>

As an aside you can avoid having to define your own `FilterRegistrationBean` by simply setting a couple configuration properties. In your `application.properties`, you could use the following

```
spring.jersey.type=filter
spring.jersey.init.jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex=<your-regex>
```

Or you can configure the regex in your `ResourceConfig` subclass

```
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        property(ServletProperties.FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX, "<your-regex>");
    }
}
```

As another side, just an FYI, the cause of the problem is the default `/*` url-mapping used for Jersey. If you *can* change it, doing so would solve the problem. For instance `/api`. You can configure that in the properties with `spring.jersey.applicationPath=/api` or with `@ApplicationPath("/api")` on the `ResourceConfig` subclass.

And the final aside, there is also a property

```
ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404
"jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404"
```

I'm not exactly sure how the staticContenRegex property works, I never really dug into to source code. So I don't know if it just does some file IO to get the static file or it forwards the request, but if it does some file IO, then I don't think the property will work for your use case, as the endpoints are not files. In which case the forwardOn404 should work.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. I have solved this problem by adding simple line in application.properties:
    server.servlet-path=/admin
This line indicates that all spring servlets are mapped to /admin/...